# Are there any places for abandoned repos to be transferred?

Tags: source-code, ownership, organisation-support

It's true that big outfits like Github aim to be around for at least the next decade or so, so arguably it's not a big deal for repos to just sit in user accounts. However, [other questions](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/549/are-you-legally-allowed-to-use-abandoned-projects) make clear that even if the project is abandoned, the copyright remains with the ostensible owner attached to that account. And anyway, in that case the account has to stay up to serve as an access point for the repo.

I wasn't able to find any information on Github, Archive Team, or Archive.org about where repos could be donated under some blanket surrender of rights. Are there any such orgs either within one of these sites or elsewhere to which a repo can be transferred?

Answer (score 5):

> the copyright remains with the ostensible owner attached to that account

Not quite, the copyright remains with the owners of the *code* (the copyright owners). In fact, if the software is under an open source license, you are perfectly within your rights to mirror the software elsewhere, even if you’re not the copyright holder. (This is what makes GitHub’s forking features legal.)

So you can push any open source project to another repository. There are a number of candidates for long-term storage, such as the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) (in their [open source collections](https://archive.org/details/open_source_software)), or perhaps [Software Heritage](https://www.softwareheritage.org/).

As far as transferring rights goes, that’s a bit more complex. The [Free Software Foundation](https://fsf.org/) has processes in place to allow developers to assign their copyrights to the Foundation, but they might not do it for any project; likewise, [Software Freedom Conservancy](https://sfconservancy.org/) accepts copyright assignments and has the legal frameworks to do so in a number of countries, but again that might just be for certain projects.